# Extracting file names from html file

Tags: r, regex, string, extract

This is a sample of the character string I'm dealing with

```
string <- c("<tr><td valign=\"top\"><img src=\"/icons/compressed.gif\" alt=\"[   ]\"></td><td><a href=\"ABC.RAP_0.9.0.zip\">ABC.RAP_0.9.0.zip</a></td><td align=\"right\">2018-03-20 21:52  </td><td align=\"right\">4.6M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>", 
            "<tr><td valign=\"top\"><img src=\"/icons/compressed.gif\" alt=\"[   ]\"></td><td><a href=\"ABCanalysis_1.2.1.zip\">ABCanalysis_1.2.1.zip</a></td><td align=\"right\">2017-12-09 13:59  </td><td align=\"right\"> 54K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>", 
            "<tr><td valign=\"top\"><img src=\"/icons/compressed.gif\" alt=\"[   ]\"></td><td><a href=\"ABCoptim_0.15.0.zip\">ABCoptim_0.15.0.zip</a></td><td align=\"right\">2018-03-20 21:53  </td><td align=\"right\">566K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>")
```

this string was produced by

```
readLines("https://dirichlet.mat.puc.cl/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/")
```

I need to extract R packages names. I can do it using `sub` like this:

```
> gsub("(.\\.zip).*", "\\1", sub(".*href[[:punct:]]{2}", "", string))
[1] "ABC.RAP_0.9.0.zip"     "ABCanalysis_1.2.1.zip" "ABCoptim_0.15.0.zip"
```

As you can see I used `gsub` twice and I'm looking for a simpler way to do it by calling `gsub` just once. I want to accomplish it using only R base functions.

Comment: `gsub('"([^>]+\\.zip)"|.', '\\1', string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can solve my problem using this simple regex:

```
> gsub(".*>(.*\\.zip)<.*", "\\1", string)
[1] "ABC.RAP_0.9.0.zip"     "ABCanalysis_1.2.1.zip" "ABCoptim_0.15.0.zip"
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Try like this with `rvest`

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://dirichlet.mat.puc.cl/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/'

packageList <- url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_text()

# remove extra entries
packageList <- packageList[7:length(packageList)]

head(packageList)

[1] "A3_1.0.0.zip"           "ABC.RAP_0.9.0.zip"      "ABCanalysis_1.2.1.zip"  "ABCoptim_0.15.0.zip"    "ABCp2_1.2.zip"         
[6] "ABHgenotypeR_1.0.1.zip"
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, your answer is great, but as I said before, I don't want rely on any extra package other than R base. +1!